# how to add a text label in the y-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'd like to add a single text label to a specified point (call it y = 1.5) of the y-axis. This will be in there as well as the regular ticks.

Is there a good way of doing this within the ggplot2 package?

Comment: Use the `breaks` parameter in the `scale_y_continuous` to specify at which point the axis-tricks have to come.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! From [ggplot2 documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html):

```
# Add a text annotation
p +
  geom_text() +
  annotate("text", label = "plot mpg vs. wt", x = 2, y = 15, size = 8, colour = "red")
```

[image: plot]
<sub>(source: [ggplot2.org](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text-28.png))</sub>

Yours would look something like `+ annotate("text", label = "your text here", x = 2, y = 1.5)`