# add additional labels to y-axis without tickmark using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Similar to this question [how to add a text label in the y-axis in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382209/how-to-add-a-text-label-in-the-y-axis-in-ggplot2), which lacks an example and a satisfying answer, I wonder wether there is any way to put additional labels on an axis, most of the time this will probably be the y-axis. The additional label should appear at a specified position. It should be possible to style the additonal label independently from the "normal" tick labels. And: it should lack a tick (whereas the "normal" tick labels may/should have ticks).

An example:

```
# Sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2.6, 3, 4, 5),
  y = c(2, 5, 3.6, 8.2, 10),
  y_ticks = c(2, 4, 5, 8, 10),
  y_labels = c("Low", "Mid-Low", "Medium", "Mid-High", "High")
)

# Create a scatter plot with custom y-axis ticks and labels
library (ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = df$y_ticks, labels = df$y_labels)
```

Which gives:

[image]

What I want is to add a label (lets say "lower values") without tickmark at y = 6.
I tried to draw it in by hand in red to demonstrate the purpose:

[image]

I already tried different things, but I cannot figure this out. Perhaps someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(6, 2.6, 3, 4, 5),
  y = c(2, 5, 3.6, 8.2, 10),
  y_ticks = c(2, 4, 5, 8, 10),
  y_labels = c("Low", "Mid-Low", "Medium", "Mid-High", "High")
)
# Create a scatter plot with custom y-axis ticks and labels
library (ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = df$y_ticks, labels = df$y_labels) +
  annotate("text", y = 6L, x = -Inf, label = "lower", col = "red", hjust = 1.2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df$x), max(df$x)), clip = "off")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here we use `annotate()` + `coord_cartesian()` with `clip = off` to allow displaying text outside the plot. We need to set the `xlim` in `coord_cartesian` for this. I found the x-position in `annotate()` by trial and error. There are certainly more sophisticated approaches.

**Edit**: As per @teunbrand's suggestion in a comment below, to automatically find a satisfactory x-position do: `x = -Inf` *to set the label at the leftmost position with* `hjust = 1` *(or larger) to have it right-justified*.

Comment: while this works, it is hard to reproduce - especially, if there are many plots to be created (which is the case for me). perhaps there is a way to extract the coordiantes of the plot automatically or place the label at a relative position with respect to the x axis (this should be a negative relative position, of course).

Comment: You can combine `x = -Inf` to set the label at the leftmost position with `hjust = 1` (or larger) to have it right-justified.

Comment: @teunbrand I have edited my answer accordingly. Thank you.